# Are guest additions useful for headless Linux guests?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

The question is "Are guest additions useful for headless Linux guests?"

I need to run several guest linux systems as a kind of build and test farm. I would also very much like to keep them as light as possible. I am therefore tying to decide between having to install additional packages and the guest additions vs. clean OS but running without optimized drivers.

How much of a penalty is there if the dedicated HD/SATA and Ethernet drivers in guest additions are not installed? Guests are headless, so display drivers are not a factor.

I would be happy if you can make negligible/significant distinction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at chapter 4 of the manual.

Guest additions is more than just about seamless windows.  It provides other features that may be useful to you such as memory ballooning, page fusion (windows only) and shared folders.

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

So, if those features are not important to you then yes, you don't have to install guest additions.

Comment: Thanks for your resonse. But my question is about a headless vm. All of the advantages seem geared to UI or interactive use, all of which do not seem relevant to headless use. Time sync also seems well taken care of by the ntp proticol and daemon. Page fusion seems limited to Windows guests...